# How to create a kafka stream in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a kafka stream and then do some transformations on that but It seems the stream that I create is null. I load a text file into producer then consume it through consumer and It works fine but it doesn't create the kafka stream.
The input text file looks like this with 36000 entries:

```
10.000000
26.000000
-8.000000
-28.000000
...
```

And my python code is:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="STALTA")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
broker, topic = sys.argv[1:]
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, broker, "raw-event-streaming-consumer",{topic:1})
rdd = kvs.flatMap(lambda line: line.strip().split("\n")).map(lambda strelem: float(strelem))
print("****** ", rdd.count())
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

`rdd.count()` should print 36000 but it's empty.

The command that I run my script with is the following:

```
bin/spark-submit --jars jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.1.jar examples/src/main/python/streaming/sparkkafka.py localhost:2181 consumer6
```

I tried localhost:9092 also but it didn't work.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried letting this code run, and then producing?

Comment: did you start streamingcontext ???

Comment: @cricket_007 It didn't work because I need to pass the topic to the program.

Comment: @nabongs : Yes, I did. And I'm getting this error:


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute

Comment: I was asking if you ran SparkSubmit with all needed arguments, which starts a consumer, and then you produced into the topic... Also, you do need to start the streaming context, so please include that line in the question

Comment: @cricket_007 I keep getting the following error when I tried your solution and I also added the streamingContext start to my code.

Error

: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute

Comment: Replace `print("****** ", rdd.count())` with `rdd.pprint()`, and that is not an RDD, it's a DStream

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you! But I'm not seeing that DStream I produced in console! I see only a timing thing:

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2018-07-17 11:13:08
-------------------------------------------

2018-07-17 11:13:08 INFO  JobScheduler:54 - Finished job streaming job 1531847588000 ms.0 from job set of time 1531847588000 ms
2018-07-17 11:13:08 INFO  JobScheduler:54 - Total delay: 0.048 s for time 1531847588000 ms (execution: 0.004 s)

Comment: @cricket_007 I just realized that I'm not able to run this sample code also on kafka. I don't know what's wrong with it!

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/kafka_wordcount.py

Comment: It'll print out a count only every few seconds that Spark gets messages from Kafka. It will not always consume from the beginning of the topic.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your respond! I was able to run that sample code but still  unable to see the printed DStream from my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the broker to the zookeeper IP, usually it's `localhost:2181` because it required the zookeeper IP not the kafka IP.

For the question to print the `DStream`, you could directly print with `kvs.pprint()` usually it will print like a tupple of rdd. Don't use the `print()` its not recognized by the sparkstreaming as output command so you will get those error.

```
Error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
```

Hope this will help you.